# Prompt for user input flexibly with interactive

Tags: interactive

I have a function that uses `smartparens` to replace specified pairs of parentheses.

```el
(defun replace-paren-at-point (paren)
  (interactive "sReplace with: ")
  (if (looking-at "[「『《〈（〔【]")
    (progn
      (set-mark-command nil)
      (forward-sexp)
      (sp-wrap-with-pair paren)
      (sp-unwrap-sexp))
    (if (save-excursion
      (backward-char)
      (looking-at "[」』》〉）〕】]"))
    (progn
      (set-mark-command nil)
      (backward-sexp)
      (sp-wrap-with-pair paren)
      (sp-unwrap-sexp)))
    (message "No parenthesis at point.")))
```

One issue with the function above is that the user would be prompted to enter the replace string before he/she is reminded that there is `"No parenthesis at point."` (in cases which the cursor is at the wrong position.)

How do I change this so that an error message appears before the user is prompted for the input?

```el
(defun replace-paren-at-point (paren)
  (interactive)
  (if (looking-at "[「『《〈（〔【]")
      (progn
        (read-string (format "Replace %s with: " (string (char-after))))
        (set-mark-command nil)
        (forward-sexp)
        (sp-wrap-with-pair paren)
        (sp-unwrap-sexp))
    (if (save-excursion
      (backward-char)
      (looking-at "[」』》〉）〕】]"))
    (progn
      (read-string (format "Replace %s with: " (string (char-before))))
      (set-mark-command nil)
      (backward-sexp)
      (sp-wrap-with-pair paren)
      (sp-unwrap-sexp)))
    (message "No parenthesis at point.")))
```

I try to use `read-string` for the input prompt but it doesn't work this way.

Seems like `read-string` has to be defined *without* the `paren` argument, but I need the `paren` variable set to store the value for the replace string. So I am kind of stuck.

---

## Settings:

In case some of you might like to test the code above, here are the settings that should be evaluated in `init.el` before running the tests.

```el
(package-initialize)
(smartparens-global-mode t)

(sp-pair "「" "」")
(sp-pair "『" "』")
(sp-pair "【" "】")
(sp-pair "《" "》")
(sp-pair "〈" "〉")
(sp-pair "（" "）")
(sp-pair "〔" "〕")
```

Comment: Can you also include some instruction on how to make this work? I don't think sp works with these special pairs out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a test for paren at point inside the `interactive` spec.
If no paren at point, raise an error.

```lisp
(defun replace-paren-at-point (paren)
  (interactive
   (if (not (or (looking-at "[「『《〈（〔【]")
                (save-excursion (backward-char) (looking-at "[」』》〉）〕】]"))))
       (error "No parenthesis at point")
     (list (read-string "Replace paren with: "))))
  (cond ((looking-at "[「『《〈（〔【]")
         (set-mark-command nil)
         (forward-sexp)
         (sp-wrap-with-pair paren)
         (sp-unwrap-sexp))
        ((save-excursion (backward-char) (looking-at "[」』》〉）〕】]"))
         (set-mark-command nil)
         (backward-sexp)
         (sp-wrap-with-pair paren)
         (sp-unwrap-sexp))))
```

(I didn't test the parts of your code. I just rearranged them. Assuming that your tests etc. do what you want, they should do that in this code too.)

Comment: It works, thanks!

Comment: Why does `read-sting` need to be nested within a `(list (read-string "Replace paren with: "))`?

Comment: `C-h f interactive`, and check the Emacs manual about `interactive` (`i interactive` in the manual). When passed a sexp to evaluate, instead of a special "interactive" string, the sexp must return a _list_ of all arguments you want to pass to the function.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same using sp functions. No need to hardcode the matching pairs.

```
(defun replace-paren-at-point ()
  (interactive)
  (cond ((sp--looking-at (sp--get-opening-regexp))
         (sp-down-sexp)
         (call-interactively 'sp-rewrap-sexp))
        ((sp--looking-back (sp--get-closing-regexp))
         (sp-backward-sexp)
         (sp-down-sexp)
         (call-interactively 'sp-rewrap-sexp))
        (t
         (user-error "No matching pair at point"))))
```

Comment: That's super cool!

Comment: When I try to rewrap with `〔` using your code, I get the following error. `user-error: Impossible pair prefix selected: \30024Error during redisplay: (eval (ergoemacs-status--eval)) signaled (error "Lisp nesting exceeds ‘max-lisp-eval-depth’")
`

Comment: Works for me, although with `emacs -Q` I have to either reload the major-mode or use `sp-local-pair`. For example: `(sp-local-pair 'lisp-interaction-mode "〔" "〕")`.